# Find the linear transformation associated with the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am looking to find vector spaces V & W and bases, ordered bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and a transformation $T$, Where M is the matrix that the transformation is describing.

$
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
   0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]  
$

I understand that I have quite a couple options for the my choices for V and W I chose $R^{4}$ & $R^{3}$ as my vectors spaces and let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ bet the standard bases. Now I'm confused on how to find the linear transformation associated with the matrix.

My first thought was to find the representation of a generic vector by the matrix but I'm not sure if that would be write. What I mean by  this is to solve the following

$
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & -1 & 0 & 2 & a_1 \\
   0 & 3 & 1 & 1 & a_2 \\
   1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & a_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]  
$

Would this be the correct way to go about this problem or do I have it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 & 2 \\
   0 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x-y+2t\\3y+z+t\\x+2z-t\end{bmatrix},$$you can define$$\begin{array}{rccc}T\colon&\mathbb{R}^4&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^3\\&(x,y,z,t)&\mapsto&(x-y+2t,3y+z+t,x+2z-t).\end{array}$$The basis will be, of course, the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: so i don't have to bother row reducing like I was trying to do?

Comment: @Aldrec No. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Thats the first way i thought about doing it, can you explain to me why thats wrong? i'm a bit confused

Comment: @Aldrec No, I can't, since I don't understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: I created an augmented matrix with a vector in $R^{3}$ and then row reduce that matrix

Comment: @Aldrec That's what I would do in order to determine the image of $T$, not to define $T$.

Comment: Ah, Okay I see would my choices for $\beta$ & $\gamma$ be satisfactory?

Comment: @Aldrec Yes, they would. That was my choice, too.

Answer (score 0):

$M\begin {bmatrix} v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4 \end {bmatrix}  = \begin {bmatrix} v_1 -
 v_2 + 2v_4\\v_2 + v_3 + v_4\\v_1 + 2v_3 -v_4\end {bmatrix}$

Comment: how would I find that?

Comment: It is just the matrix $M$ times a generic vector in $V$